# C# net core ConverterEnum

Tags: c#, .net-core, сериализация

Возникла очень интересная проблема
при конвертации Enum в объекте Dto
JsonSerializer кушает его спокойно, если мы передадим в строчке "2342342" число
для enum:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    Ad = 0,
    Bd = 1,
 }
```

при объявлении атрибута enumdatatypeattribute все работает
А как сделать это в сетапе?
возможно ли настроить все в сетапе?
Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой подскажите пожалуйста что сделать можно
Есть ли какая-то альтернатива атрибуту "enumdatatypeattribute"?
Примечание: Речь идет о сериализации формы в контроллере

Comment: Настроить что? Вы передаёте невалидное значение атрибута 2345243 и какое поведение вы считаете "нормальным"?  В Json.net [можно указать в настройках сериализатора](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31651523/5752652) желаемое поведение (подавить exception), но похоже что у вас штатный коровский json, я не уверен, что там уже есть что-то похожее - слишком молодая библиотека, хотя не копал, не знаю точно.

Comment: @AK на кастомном конвертере можно, только смысел передавать невалидное значение.

Comment: @aepot а как сделать кастомный конвертер 
я сейчас пытался его сделать там нужно очень много недоступных опций

Comment: @AK в настройках сериализатора можно указать лишь проверку на ренж числа 
То есть когда приходит число 2242 он его не пропустит 
А вот если придет число в строке "2242" он его почему-то спокойно пропускает 
И как это сделать без атрибута я не понимаю

Comment: @aepot Речь идет об открытом Апи 
И если рассматривать запрос с невалидным значением, то система сломается тк не будет обработано значение не входящее в enum

Comment: @ДанилЧерных почему сломается? ловите исключение, возвращайте ошибку клиенту. Вы пытаетесь воткнуть костыль туда, где его быть не должно.

Comment: @aepot представте что у нас система состоит из 5000 дто и функций в контроллере
И проблема заключается лишь в том что сериализатор не валидирует нормально енам 
И если делать так как вы предлагаете, нужно будет в 5000 местах это делать? 
Или добавлять атрибут в 5000 мест? 
Должно же быть какое то универсальное решение?))

Comment: @ДанилЧерных зачем валидировать невалидный enum? Пришли кривые данные - вернуть ошибку клиенту. Если у вас обработка ошибок десереализации не реализована, то у вас что-то не так с архитектурой апишечки.

Comment: @aepot так  а как тогда валидировать не валидный енам?) 
Есть предложения

Comment: Возникнет исключение при десереализации.

Comment: @aepot у меня не возникает исключения 
В этом то и проблема
Говорю же что "42342" и подобные числа он спокойно пропускает

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot вообще никак 
Мне нужно создать конвертер для Enum

Comment: Ну тогда извините, что не смог помочь.

Comment: @aepot у вас нет знакомых которые сталкивались с такой проблемой?

Comment: @ДанилЧерных нет.